# sObject in visualforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have an apex controller which builds up a list to be displayed in a datatable. The list combines different object, so the variable I create is a List

Say all the objects in this list have an "external__c" field. How do I tell the visualforce to render this field? Using {!obj.external__c} will not work since it is an sObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got a list of SObjects you can get a common field using `obj.get('external__c')` though you generally have to cast the result to a type to be able to use it.

You can create a custom class in code which you can fill with various objects:

```
// inside the controller do this:
public class COutputObject
{
    private SObject sObj = null;
    public  string  strField get {return (string)sObj.get('external__c'); }

    public COutputObject(SObject s)
    {
        sObj = s;
    }
}

// -- snip --

// then have a list of these which you'll loop over in the page
public list<COutputObject> liObjects = new list<COutputObject>();

// fill this with data
for(CustomObj__c sCustom : [select Id, external__c from CustomObj__c limit 200])
{
    liObjects.add(new COutputObject(sCustom));
    // etc.

for(CustomObj2__c sCustom : [select Id, external__c from CustomObj2__c limit 200])
{
    liObjects.add(new COutputObject(sCustom));
    // etc.
```

Not 100% sure if my syntax on the getter is correct, but it's close ;) Hopefully this will help you achieve what you're after!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the list property is declared like so in your controller: `Public List<Beer__c> ColdOnes { get; set; }`.  Well in Visualforce, you reference the beers by their property name in the controller... `{!ColdOnes}`.  The following is mostly taken from the Visualforce guide, but I have adapted it to suit our thist-quenching subject matter :)

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!ColdOnes}" var="co" id="theTable" rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="tableClass">

    <apex:facet name="caption">table caption</apex:facet>

    <apex:facet name="header">table header</apex:facet>

    <apex:facet name="footer">table footer</apex:facet>

    <apex:column>

            <apex:facet name="header">Beer Name</apex:facet>

        <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>

        <apex:outputText value="{!co.name}"/>

    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>

            <apex:facet name="header">Alcohol Volume</apex:facet>

        <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>

        <apex:outputText value="{!co.alcohol_volume__c}"/>

    </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

Just be aware that if you are setting ColdOnes with a queried value in your code, you need to select the fields you intend to output in your Visualforce.  So:

```
ColdOnes=[select name, alcohol_volume__c from Beer__c where blahblahblah];
```

Well, I'm off for a pint.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh hang on, do you mean the List contains sObjects?  Now that is a different matter...  How about instead of using sObject, you use a 'catch-all' custom object with the common fields between the assortment of objects, make a List of said custom object, then just re-cast the sObject list as a list of the custom object in question?  I mean, I've never tried it, but it should work in theory...  (Anyway, I'm leaving this time, beer)

Comment: Correct, sObjects. I used that 'catch-all' custom object idea as you mentioned, but we're having problems with a client. They're having problems where only the installing user is able to create the custom object in the managed package. I was hoping using sObject in its place would mitigate the issue.

Comment: I'm assuming the controller is a with sharing class then?

What edition is your client on? If they're on Enterprise or Unlimited, they can just set cruds for the custom object and its fields by profile.  If they're on Professional, I think you'll have to find a workaround.  Assuming the answer is yes to the 'with sharing' question, try making the relevent properties/methods static.  As statics are initialised before class creation, you should be able to work around crud issues provided that is scalable for the rest of your code.

Comment: Turns out the issue was that the package needs to be manually deployed after installation... I would have expected an error saying unable to access object because it is not deployed, but there was no feedback. Oh well, at least we don't have to make some workaround :/ thanks for the help